# Interactive Grid shows no results when filtered or sorted

Tags: oracle-apex, interactive-grid

I am using Oracle Apex v21.1. I have an Interactive Grid on a Modal Dialog Page which gives me the logs of the modifications made on a certain item.

Here's the scenario :

1. Select the item on the list [Step 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mQGYH.png)
2. The details page of the item opens
3. Click on the "Logs" button [Step 2 & 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ry1CP.png)
4. The "Logs" button open another Modal Dialog Page which displays an interactive grid [Step 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nBKKp.png)
5. The "Logs" button set the value of the primary key to the interactive grid, so the list is filtered to show the information of this particular item. [Step 5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qejer.png)

[Everything works fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A3nv7.png), but when I try to apply a filter, sort or search, the interactive grid refresh, [shows no data, and a blank column appears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wgy1K.png). If I close the list but reopen it again, [the results are appearing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vuwMT.png), based on the filter, sort or search.

What could be the reason behind this problem ?

Here's the code of my Interactive Grid

```
SELECT * FROM inv_tb_item_logs
WHERE pk_article = :P24_PK_ARTICLE;   --pk_article is my primary key
```

You can see more details on the screenshots

Thank you in advance,

Thomas

Comment: Do you have P24_PK_ARTICLE in the "Page items to submit" attribute of the interactive grid ?

Comment: Hello Koen Lostrie. Thank you for your answer which led me to the right path. I'll answer to my own question with the details on how to solve it. Thanks you very much !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on Koen Lostrie's answers, here's how to fix it :

1. Create an **Hidden Item** to retrieve the ID of the Item later on the Logs List page [Step 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xe6AN.png)
2. In the Behaviour of the Logs button, set the value of the hidden item to the value of the ID of the Item [Step 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3b7Mf.png)
3. Change the WHERE clause to `WHERE id_item = :P25_PK_ARTICLE`
4. In the **Page Item to Submit** attribute, select **P25_PK_ARTICLE**

I had to create this specific hidden item because i couldn't select the P24_PK_ARTICLE item to submit since it was on another page.

I hope this could help other people, thanks again for your answer Koen !